# XML element ordering

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <table>
            <row>
                <description2>ABC</description2>
            </row>
            <row>
                <description2>DEF</description2>
            </row>
            <row>
                <description2>GHI</description2>
            </row>
            <row>
                <description1>JKL</description1>
                <message>msg1</message>
            </row>
            <row>
                <description1>MNO</description1>
                <message>msg2</message>
            </row>
        </table>
```

I want all the row node which contain *description2* child node to be displayed after the row node which contains *description*

SO my resultant XML would look like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
    <row>
        <description1>JKL</description1>
        <message>msg1</message>
    </row>
    <row>
        <description1>MNO</description1>
        <message>msg2</message>
    </row>
    <row>
        <description2>ABC</description2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <description2>DEF</description2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <description2>GHI</description2>
    </row>
</table>
```

How do I achieve that in XSLT?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried? Thank you.

Comment: @Tim C Hi, I am not aware of XSLT. Please help me if you can comply my requirements. Thank you .

Comment: @TimC Hi, I am not aware of XSLT. Please help me if you can comply my requirements. Thank you .

Comment: Try searching for ["identity transform"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and [`xsl:sort`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-sort), attempt to create the XSLT yourself, and then update your question if/when you get stuck.